# Showing that mean of vectors minimizes the sum of the squared distances.

Tags: optimization, means

Let $S=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Now we have to pick a vector $\mu$, such that the following expression is minimized:

$$
L(\mu)=\sum_{x\in S} ||x-\mu||_2^2.
$$

I think that the best option to minimize $L(\mu)$, would be to use the mean of the vectors as $\mu$. However, I can't prove why this is so.

Here's a complete answer that I solved thanks to the help of David K.

$$
\begin{align*}
\mu^*&= \arg\min_\mu \sum_{x\in S} ||x-\mu||_2^2
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu \sum_{x\in S} <x-\mu,x-\mu>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu \sum_{x\in S} \big(<x,x> -2<x,\mu>+<\mu,\mu>\big)
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu n<\mu,\mu>-2\sum_{x\in S}<x,\mu>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu n<\mu,\mu>-2n\left<\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in S}x,\mu\right>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu <\mu,\mu>-2<\overline{x},\mu>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu <\mu,\mu>-2<\overline{x},\mu> + <\overline{x},\overline{x}>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu <\mu-\overline{x},\mu-\overline{x}>
\\
&= \arg\min_\mu ||\mu-\overline{x}||_2^2.
\end{align*}
$$
The $||\cdot ||_2$ can never be smaller than $0$. Therefore, choosing $\mu=\overline{x}$ minimizes the expression, as $||\mu-\overline{x}||_2^2$ becomes $0$. Hence, $\mu^*=\overline{x}$.

Comment: You can remove the $n$ in line 5 because its a constant multiplier and has no effect on the solution when optimizing for $\mu$, right?

Comment: @Chris Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the symbol $\mu$ is already in use in the question,
let's write $\bar x$ to denote the mean of the vectors in $S$; that is,
$$
\bar x = \frac1n \sum_{x\in S} x.
$$

Then by the linearity of the inner product,
\begin{align}
\sum_{x\in S} \langle x, \mu\rangle
 &= \left\langle \sum_{x\in S} x, \mu\right\rangle \\
 &= n \left\langle \frac1n\sum_{x\in S} x, \mu\right\rangle \\
 &= n \left\langle \bar x, \mu\right\rangle. \\
\end{align}

With this, you can eliminate the individual $x$s from your last
formula, leaving only $\mu$ and $\bar x$.

Now consider the quantity $\lVert \mu - \bar x\rVert_2^2$.
That's something that clearly minimized when $\mu = \bar x$,
since the norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert_2$ can never be less than zero.
That is,
$$
\arg\min_\mu \, \lVert \mu - \bar x\rVert_2^2 = \bar x \tag1
$$
So it would be really convenient if we could reduce your minimization
problem to something that looks like the left-hand side of Equation $(1)$.

Now consider some of the techniques you already used in your first attempt.
You know that 
$\lVert \mu - \bar x\rVert_2^2 = 
\lVert\mu\rVert_2^2 - 2 \langle\mu,\bar x\rangle + \lVert\bar x\rVert_2^2$,
and you know you can add or subtract a constant from the value inside the
$\arg\min$ without changing the $\mu$ that minimizes the value.
Also notice that in your second attempt, you found that 
$$
\mu^* = \arg\min_\mu \, (- 2 \langle\bar x,\mu\rangle + \lVert\mu\rVert_2^2).
$$

At this point, you're just a couple of steps away from showing
that $\mu^* = \bar x$.
(I'm trying not to spoil this too much, because it's so much fun
when a problem resolves like this, especially when you get to make
the final "aha!" step yourself.)

Comment: Thank you! That got me a bit further. However, I'm still stuck at the very last step. Do you have a good argument for justifying $\mu=\overline{x}$ on the last line?

Comment: It's probably easier if you back up a couple of lines. I extended the answer a bit to show what I had in mind.

Comment: This is very neat!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @DavidK! I've written down a complete answer that uses the tricks you showed me.

Comment: I looked at your revisions to the proof in your question, they look fine to me!

Comment: I'm writing an algorithm for a similar problems in The Advent of Code : https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/7 and I think in part two have to minimise the Sum of Arithmetic Progression terms for integer vectors to find the solution. Perhaps this should be another question, but if you are intrigued and have an idea let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Since $S = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ is finite let $L(\mu) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} ||x_i-\mu||_2^2$, which is a function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In the following I will use upper indices to denote the respective components of the vectors involved, e.g. $x_1 = (x_1^1, x_1^2, ... x_1^d)$. Calculating the partial derivatives of $L(\mu)$ with respect to $\mu^k$ where $1 \leq k \leq d$ we get

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu^k} = 2n\mu^k - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^k$.
Now, if we want this to vanish we get

$2n\mu^k - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^k = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mu^k = 1/n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^k$.

That is $\mu = \frac{1}{n} \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^1 \\...\\ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^d \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j$.

Now you need to go on and prove this gives a global minima for $L$.

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to also have an approach that uses derivation. The end would involve building the Hesse matrix and showing that it's positive definite (and it most likely will be symmetric and thus positive definite).